# standard outputread does not read anything until process is closed vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, process, command-prompt, redirectstandardoutput

I am trying to redirect the output from [xfoil.exe](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/) with downloadables [here](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/XFOIL6.99.zip). The issue is when I am redirecting the standardoutput, my code will not read anything until I use the "quit" command which closes the external xfoil.exe and hence, I cannot run any further commands.

first defining variables

```
Dim p as process = New Process()
Dim startinfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
Dim bt As Threading.Thread
```

I start the process using

```
With startinfo
    .FileName = Application.StartupPath & "\appdata\xfoil.exe"
    .Arguments = ""
    .WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath
    .RedirectStandardError = True
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .RedirectStandardInput = True
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .CreateNoWindow = True
End With

p.StartInfo = startinfo
p.EnableRaisingEvents = True

If Not IsNothing(bt) Then bt.Abort()
bt = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ReadThread)
bt.IsBackground = True
bt.Start()
p.Start()
```

The definition for the ReadThread is

```
Private Sub ReadThread()
    Dim rLine As String
    Do Until Leaving
        Try
            rLine = p.StandardOutput.Read()
            logtext += (Chr(rLine))
            If p.StandardOutput.Peek = -1 Then
                Me.Invoke(Sub() txtLog.AppendText(logtext))
                logtext = ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("error  " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    Loop
End Sub
```

This setup works perfectly with another app from the same developer Mark Drela. When I use the other app [AVL](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/avl/) with download link [here](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/avl/avl3.36.exe.zip) everything works fine. However, xfoil does not work with this setup and I have spent some hours on this without any luck. I am using VB.net on Windows 10 in Visual Studio.NET 2019 community edition.

**Edit**
Both methods using *threading* and *events* were implemented and no luck.

A sample code using both methods in VB.net is [now available on Github](https://github.com/afrahimi/XFoil_Console) for review comments. Let me know if anyone has any experience with this and can help. This would really help my students in the class!

Comment: Use the **Events** (`OutputDataReceived`, `ErrorDataReceived`) generated by the Process class to handle new data. `EnableRaisingEvents` is only used to explicitly raise the `Exited` event, not the others. Set the [Process.SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject) to the instance of the parent Form/Window of your TextBox controls, so you don't even need to Invoke (and you should `BeginInvoke()` here). Don't use a Thread for this.

Comment: Hi @Jimi I did try both and uploaded a code in vb.net on github at https://github.com/afrahimi/XFoil_Console. Please take a look and let me know where things are wrong